# Sum unequal and removing duplicates from SQL query results

Tags: mysql, sql, database, logic

My base query:

```
SELECT project_id
       name
       stories_produced
       on_date
      FROM project_prod
      WHERE on_date IN ('2017-03-01', '2017-06-10')
      ORDER BY project_id
```

It can get me these outputs:

Output example:

```
id       name                   stories_produced        on_date
1042    project 1               1001 (wanted)           2017-03-01
1042    project 1               1801 (wanted)           2017-06-10
1568    project 2               355  (wanted)           2017-06-10
1405    project 3               1    (not wanted)       2017-03-10
1405    project 3               1    (not wanted)       2017-06-10
```

Obs: There is a constraint on (id, on_date) meaning there can always be only one record of a project production on a specific date.

Duplicate records, that have the same id, and exist in both dates and have **different** production values *(wanted)*

Single records, that exists on only one of the dates (wanted)

**The problem:***

Duplicate records, that have the same id, and exist in both dates and have **equal** production values *(not wanted)*

My current query, that need change

```
      select project_id 
        name 
        CASE
          WHEN max(stories_produced) - min(stories_produced) = 0    
          THEN max(stories_produced)
          ELSE max(stories_produced) - min(stories_produced)
        END AS 'stories_produced'
        from project_prod
      WHERE on_date IN ('2017-03-01', '2017-06-10')
      group by project_id;
```

output example:

```
id       name                   stories_produced        
1042    project 1               800 (wanted)
1568    project 2               355  (wanted)
1405    project 3               1    (not wanted)
```

The CASE is currently **not** taking care of the third constraint (Duplicate records, that have the same id, and exist in both dates and have EQUAL production values *(not wanted)*)

Is there any possible condition that can accommodate this?

Comment: You data does not show the date associated to each record, while it seems like an important piece of information here.

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your question

Comment: You are right @GMB on the first base query, I forgot to add them. Edited now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses `not exists` to drop rows *that have the same id, and exist in both dates and have equal production values*:

```
select
    p.project_id,
    p.name,
    p.stories_produced,
    p.on_date,
  from project_prod p
  where 
    on_date in ('2017-03-01', '2017-06-10')
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from project_prod p1
        where 
            p1.on_date in ('2017-03-01', '2017-06-10')
            and p1.on_date <> p.date
            and p1.id = p.id 
            and p1.stories_produced = p.stories_produced

    )
  order by project_id
```

In MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions:

```
select
    project_id,
    name,
    stories_produced,
    on_date,
from (
    select 
        p.*,
        min(stories_produced) over(partition by project_id) min_stories_produced,
        max(stories_produced) over(partition by project_id) max_stories_produced,
        count(*) over(partition by project_id) max_stories_produced cnt
    from project_prod p
    where on_date in ('2017-03-01', '2017-06-10')
) t
where not (cnt = 2 and min_stories_produced = max_stories_produced)
oder by project_id
```

Comment: Wish I was using version 8, it is way cleaner

Comment: Thanks a lot! GMB, I just replaced <> by equal and, it worked fine